# How to update queries upon change of dropdown selection in Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I'm a complete beginner and I'm trying to figure out Razor / ASP.net /  C# (any useful resources would be helpful)

I want to update a query based on a dropdown selection:

Here's what I have:

```
@{
Page.Title = "Home";

var db = Database.Open("OutreachModule");
var people = db.Query("SELECT * FROM PEOPLE").ToList();

var items = people.Select(i => new SelectListItem {
Text = i.name
});

}
@functions {
void itemSelected() {
    Console.Write("hello world");
    }
 }
```

...HTML...

```
@Html.DropDownList("Select1",items,new {onchange = "itemSelected()"})
```

...more HTML ...

I know the @functions thing isn't the way to go. The dropdown works, the itemSelected method is called but it says it's not defined. I assume this is because it's looking for a javascript function. Is there a way for the change of the selection of the dropdown to trigger Razor code so that I can re-run the queries etc on the selected person (for example) ?

Comment: If you are using MVC you need to look into the usage of controllers. take a look here [asp.net](http://www.asp.net)

Comment: What should I use? MVC, web pages, web forms? I don't fully understand which is which and what the key differences are.

Comment: As above, you need to look at Controllers.  You should have C# code like you do - connecting to database etc.  This should be in it's own C# code that the Controller calls.  Useful resources would be the likes of PluralSight (google it) and http://www.asp.net/mvc (many tutorials to go through here)

Comment: I'm using WebMatrix, don't think it has controllers...

Comment: I agree. You're putting the cart before the horse here. Spend some time going through the tutorials on asp.net, and read the descriptions of the various components there. You have to walk before you can run.

Comment: Oops, my comment above should have read, "You shouldn't have C# code like you do", not "You should have C# code like you do".

Comment: Don't use WebMatrix. Honestly, not sure why it even exists. Seems like another attempt by Microsoft to make web development easy for business managers and other folks that don't know anything about web development - Front Page for the new millennium. If you want to do anything real, go with Visual Studio. Even the free Express for Web version is perfectly capable.

Comment: Ah, ok. Can you build databases and serve up web pages in Visual studio?

Comment: @shim read the links above - it'll explain data access etc... http://asp.net/mvc is probably the best web site as it's free.

Comment: 100% use MVC, I hate web forms. Use MVC so much easier, better ... in most cases!